# Batch "SET" command

Tags: batch-file

I keep seeing "set y=%y:~0,-2%" or some visual equivalent to it in code, but I have no idea what it's called, what it does, or how it's syntax works; I haven't been able to find an explanation, just more uses of it. Can some one explain?

Comment: On a windows command line, run `help set` which yields plenty of documentation.

Comment: Basically it's the syntax for substrings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "Set" sets the value of a Windows variable.

   EX: `set myvar=abc` <= assigns the string "abc" to variable "%myvar"
2. "%" deferences the current value of a Windows Variable.

   EX: `echo %myvar%` <= prints "abc"
3. The `%y:~0,-2` syntax extracts a [substring](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) from the current value of the variable
   <= extracts last 2 characters from Windows variable "%y"

Here are some useful links that might help :

- [Tricks with Command Line Arguments](http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/part-2-variables.html)
- [Command line Parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- [Variable substitution](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

Answer (score 0):

Set is used to set variables eg.: `set /p A=` will ask the user for input.

in cmd type `set /?`